# Can't fetch hashed password for login form in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I made a login form, and while the registration form is fully functional, the login form doesn't seem to be working. `$user` and `$pwd` get declared, but `$pwd_hashed` stayes empty.

```
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
   $user = $_POST['user'];
   $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = :user");
   $result = $stmt->execute(array('user' => $user));
   $pwd_hash = $stmt->fetch();

   if ($pwd_hash !== false && password_verify($pwd, $pwd_hash['password'])) {
      $_SESSION['userid'] = $pwd_hash['id'];
      die('Login successful<br>');
   } else {
      $errorMessage = "Username or password doesn't match<br>";
   }
}
if(isset($errorMessage)) {
   echo $errorMessage;
}
```

Should the code work like this and I just got something wrong with naming, or is there an error in the code?

Comment: What is `$success['id']`?

Comment: oh, it should be `$pwd_hash` aswell, thanks for pointing that out. This error is unrelated to my original problem an the issue still persists though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form is included in another site, in which a database was already selected. By removing it (`;dbname=test`) and specifying the users data base (`users.users`) the issue is gone.